# How to create a regexp that matches a pattern except for some strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I work in Ruby, and have to create a single regexp for the following task, as I'm working with someone else's gem that uses this regexp to match fields to be worked on in a text file. I need to match beginning of string, any set of characters, and underscore, then any multi-digit integer that is not 1,2, 9, or 10, and end of string.
I.e., I want the following to match:

```
foo_4
bar_8
baz_120
```

BUT NOT:

```
foo_1
bar_9
baz_10
```

I tried

```
/^.+_(^(1|2|9|10))$/
```

but it did not work as apparently `^` only "negates" characters in brackets, not submatches.

Comment: So, the ending integer has to be multi-digit, right? If that's the case, then you don't need to check for 1, 2, or 9, I would think. I'm trying to find the write expression, but I'm a newby at regular expressions. Edit: nevermind as by the time I finished this you had edited your post. :)

Comment: Hello.  Since this is your first question on Stack Overflow, I edited it for it to look like a question that's considered "well-written" here.  Please, try to describe your problem with more generic words (check the title I wrote), so other people can search for your question and re-use if they encounter the same problem.  Also, pay attention to formatting (read tips and click the `?` at the editing page), since good formatting is a key to success.   In other words, welcome to SO!

Comment: I understand, but it won't let me comment on the question.  I think it's because my reputation is only at 38 right now.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Xstream, then, perhaps you should spend some time for earning reputation instead of writing comments?

Comment: I'm trying.  I've spent more time than I should on here today researching for work but at the same time trying to help people with their questions so that I can get points for reputation.  Sorry if this is an inconvenience to you guys.  :(

Comment: @XstreamINsanity: Sorry I forgot that there is that reputation limit. I upvoted one of your other answers so that next time you want to ask the OP a question you can write it in a comment. :)

Comment: :)  Thanks, I do appreciate it.  Now I have to make sure I keep my dumb answers to a minimum as I've been down bumped a few times today.  :)

Comment: Do you mean "match the beginning of the **string** " or "match the beginning of the **line** ". It makes a difference if the input can contain new lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outside of a character class the `^` symbol means start of line. I think you want a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead:

```
/^.+_(?!(?:1|2|9|10)$)\d+$/
```

See it in action on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/vmZJOIo4St).

Comment: `^` means start of line, not start of string. `\A` means start of string.

Comment: no. `^` **always** means start of line, no matter whether you use the `m` flag to perform multiline matching or not. You can only ignore the difference when you're sure that the string you're matching against has no newlines in it.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: Sorry, you are right - I check and in Ruby it does always mean start of line (in most other regular expression engines ^ means start of string and I assumed Ruby was the same). I fixed my post. Thanks for being so persistent!

Comment: Shocking truth. I also thought `^` marked the beginning of the string, surprised to know that it actually represents newline.